# TestFX with JUnit4: How can I press the ENTER key in a certain TextField?

Tags: javafx, testfx

I want to test, if a certain `TextField` (maybe there are several `TextFields`) has an `EventHandler` set via `setOnAction`. In the test code I can set the content (e.g. "HelloWorld") into the `TextField`. In my understanding I have to place the curser at the end of the text in the TextField and then, call `press(KeyCode.ENTER)`. Is there a TestFX call to place the curser a a certain point within a certain TextField? Or is there another way to test this?

Regards, Jörg

[EDIT]
Here is an example:

```
package testestfx;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class SimpleGui extends VBox {
  private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger =
          org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleGui.class);

  private TextField field1;
  private TextField field2;
  private Label label;

  public SimpleGui() {
    field1 = new TextField("Textfield1");
    field2 = new TextField("Textfield2");
    field1.setOnAction((event) -> onActionDoThis());
    field2.setOnAction((event) -> onActionDoThat());
    label = new Label("Label");
    getChildren().addAll(field1, field2 );
  }

  public TextField getField1() {
    return field1;
  }

  public TextField getField2() {
    return field2;
  }

  public Label getLabel() {
    return label;
  }

  void onActionDoThis() {
    logger.info("This");
    label.setText("This");
  }

  void onActionDoThat() {
    logger.info("That");
    label.setText("That");
  }
}
```

And here is the test:

```
package testtestfx;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.testfx.framework.junit.ApplicationTest;
import testestfx.SimpleGui;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;


public class TestSimpleGUI extends ApplicationTest {
  private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger =
          org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestSimpleGUI.class);
  private SimpleGui gui;

  @Override
  public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    super.start(stage);
    gui = new SimpleGui();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(gui));
    stage.show();
  }

  @Test
  public void testEnterKeystroke() {
    TextField t2 = gui.getField2();
    TextField t1 = gui.getField1();
    Label l1 = gui.getLabel();
    t2.setText("bar");
    t1.setText("foo");
    press(KeyCode.ENTER);
    assertEquals("That", l1.getText());
  }

}
```

The console output is:

````
15:43:29.366 [JavaFX Application Thread] [INFO] SimpleGui - This

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :That
Actual   :This

```
````

Comment: what's the problem, exactly? Just do it ..

Comment: The problem is, that the press(KeyCode.ENTER) seems always to go to the first TextField in the component. How can I test a second TextField in the component?

Comment: make sure it's focused ..

Answer (score 0):

You can set the focus on a TextField like this:

```
myTextField.requestFocus();
```

kind regards

Amadeus